# Azure App - We couldn't sign you in. Please Try again. But I'm signed in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I've an .Net web app which is using Azure AD for authentication and authorization. On development machine, Azure AD login works fine. Prodcution server has SSL installed. I did the following on both the Test and Prod servers

- Created self-signed cert in IIS
- Installed the cert under Certificates -> Personal on the web server
- Exported the installed cert.
- Uploaded the .cert in my app on Azure under Certificates and secrets.

Under Authentication in my app registered on Azure, I have following Redirect URL's

https://domainname.com/myappname
https://domainname.com/myappname/signin-oidc

Front-channel logout URL is https://domainname.com/myappname/signout-callback-oidc

When I sign in to the app, it shows me the following screen

[image]

Sign in logs show I'm signed in but the redirect is not happening as it happens to development machine. Any ideas what is causing this?